# jQuery BlockUI in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, jquery-blockui

jQuery BlockUI works on IE very well, so this is the absolute problem for me :D

Well, I want a waiting gif for default message:

```
var message = "<img src='/img/ajax-loader2.gif' width='32' height='32'>";
$.blockUI.defaults.message = message;
```

This type works in IE and broke in FF (shows an image like can't load it), and Chrome doesn't show something. :(

Has anybody an idea to force showing this nice gif?

Comment: Now firefox is OK: `$('div.blockOverlay').addClass('customMessage');` but chrome is showing empty image...

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and works fine for chrome and firefox:

```
var msg = "<img src='/img/ajax-loader2.png' width='32' height='32'>";
$.blockUI({message: msg});
```

and if u want to unblock it just use:

```
$.unblockUI();
```

Comment: Yeah, thx, I used message this way too, but can't help for me... I watched chrome's web developer tool, it says image is there but can't see... Then I added that class like above, and in firefox it works... (it's interesting, if I don't add class, it shows in firefox a broken image, I add class with the gif background,  firefox shows background and image too... chrome doesn't...)

Comment: i tihnk you should put a png image. png image works fine at my chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Method1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
    $(document).ready( () {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="/img/ajax-loader2.gif" />'}); 
   });
</script>
```

Method2:
May this link will helps to u,
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424828/chrome-firefox-doesnt-display-images-in-objects-shown-in-beforeunload-event)