# Chrome / Firefox doesn't display images in objects shown in beforeunload event

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, onbeforeunload, blockui, jquery-blockui

I'm using jQuery blockUI plugin to show some nifty "loader" on each AJAX call and each URL change.

Here is full code responsible for that:

```
var rootPath = document.body.getAttribute("data-root");

$.blockUI.defaults.message = '<h3><img style="margin: 0 5px 5px 0" src="' + rootPath + '/images/process.gif" width="48" height="48" />In progress...</h3>';
$.blockUI.defaults.css.top = '45%';

$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){$.blockUI();});
```

Everything is fine during AJAX call, however, I've noticed that Chrome and Firefox does display animated image (given in `$.blockUI.defaults.message`), during page reload, that is, during `beforeunload`.

Is this a bug in these browsers? Or is it a documented standard, that only IE breaks (which displays image without any problems). BTW: Animated `.gif` is not a problem, both Firefox and Chrome fails to display even static `.png` problem.

Can this be somehow workaround? I would like to have exactly the same loaders both at AJAX calls and page redirects / URL changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, dropping the `<img>` idea in favor of CSS and classes:

```
<div id="blockui-animated-content" style="display: none; padding: 15px">
    <div style="margin-right: 7px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block">
        <i class="icon-cog icon-spin icon-3x"></i>
    </div>
    <div style="font-size: 28px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block">
        Proszę czekać! Operacja w toku...
    </div>
</div>
```

Changing blockUI plugin call to:

```
$.blockUI.defaults.message = $('#blockui-animated-content');
$.blockUI.defaults.css.top = '45%';

$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){$.blockUI();});
```

Now, all works just fine, both in AJAX and URL change. Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question: "*Why Firefox and Chrome doesn't display images from `<img>` tags in `onbeforeunload` event?*".

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like yout rootpath is not allways what you excpect it to be.

I would suggest adding the loading message to the dom and set it inline to display : none.

Now when you toggle the visibility in the developer tools you can inspect that that your loading image is displayed correctly. This is a prerequisite for the correct behavior.

You can assign a Jquery enhanced DOM Element directly to the message property and $.blockUI will use the content of that piece for the block message.

```
$.blockUI.defaults.message = $('#loadingMessage');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/straeger/gxzbE/2/

I hope I could help you...

Comment: No, this is checked and verified. The same path is used for AJAX as for URL change and I managed to verify using Chrome Dev Tools, that path is correct and Chrome can display image -- only, for reason unknown to me, it can display it only while in Dev Tools clicking on the path. It does not display it in page, however.