# Why this Javascript does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've a piece of code in Javascript that works in Chrome and Firefox but don't work in IE. The code supposed to change CSS background-image when mouse hover some div and remove background-image when mouse is out.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expositores1').hover(function() {
        $('.expositores1').css('background-image', 'url(/wp-content/themes/kallyas/images/mapa/piso0/inter_piso0_r5_c2_f4.jpg)', 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
        $('.expositores2').css('background-image', 'url(/wp-content/themes/kallyas/images/mapa/piso0/inter_piso0_r12_c2_f2.jpg)', 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
        $('.expositores3').css('background-image', 'url(/wp-content/themes/kallyas/images/mapa/piso0/inter_piso0_r12_c4_f2.jpg)', 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
        $('.expositores4').css('background-image', 'url(/wp-content/themes/kallyas/images/mapa/piso0/inter_piso0_r14_c3_f2.jpg)', 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
    });
    $('.expositores1').mouseout(function() {
        $('.expositores1').css('background-image', 'none');
        $('.expositores2').css('background-image', 'none');
        $('.expositores3').css('background-image', 'none');
        $('.expositores4').css('background-image', 'none');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="expositores1"></div>
<div class="expositores2"></div>
<div class="expositores3"></div>
<div class="expositores4"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.expositores1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 306px;
    height: 122px;
    margin-left: 11px;
    margin-top: 146px;
}
.expositores2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 81px;
    height: 127px;
    margin-left: 11px;
    margin-top: 268px;
}
.expositores3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 185px;
    height: 127px;
    margin-left: 132px;
    margin-top: 268px;
}
.expositores4{
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: 92px;
    margin-top: 304px;
}
```

Anyone can help? Why it works in Chrome and Firefox but does not work in IE?

Regards,
Hugo

Comment: When you say not working, which part is not working? Do you see image or not, is the problem on mouse over or mouse out?

Comment: Which versions of IE have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm using IE10.
What doesn't work is the hover. So, I'm hover divs and the background-image is not changed.

Comment: Why are you using `.hover()` and `.mouseout()`? (They're not opposites - if you pass a single function to `.hover()` it will be called when the mouse enters and when it leaves.)

Comment: Apart from your question, you should check the coding style. You should not hardcode all those $('.expositoresX'). Create a loop or somthing that start's at the second element.

Comment: I tried your code in IE10 and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/deTzA/ (except I didn't have access to your images, obviously, so I used other images as placeholders).

Answer (score 6):

You're using jQuery `css()` function incorrectly.

If you want to set only one property, use: `.css('prop', 'value')`.

If you need to set multiple properties at once, you have to pass an `object`. and in your case:

```
.css({
     'background-image':'url(/wp-content/themes/kallyas/images/mapa/piso0/inter_piso0_r5_c2_f4.jpg)',
     'background-repeat':'no-repeat'
    });
```

Also, as @Miro Markarian [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17446125/1625737), you really should rely on CSS `:hover` directives to achieve that, instead of JavaScript.

Comment: That's true, but then why does OP find it "works" in some browsers? (I would expect jQuery would just ignore the extra arguments and use the first two, though I haven't checked the code.)

Comment: I just checked and indeed jQuery simply ignores the extra parameters.

Comment: @nnnnnn Well... I think there might be many factors, that are responsible for something working in one browser and not working in another one. For example, [I'm struggling with a very similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424828/chrome-firefox-doesnt-display-images-in-objects-shown-in-beforeunload-event), where image doesn't show up in FF / Chrome, but does in IE.

Comment: It might be something to do with the format of the image URLs, because the OP's code worked for me in IE10 here: http://jsfiddle.net/deTzA/ - but I didn't have their images so I had to substitute placeholder images with a different path...

Comment: Yes, but the :hover only change "this" background-image, not a set of div's background-images. Right?

Comment: @HugoSousa yes, but it still can be done using css, although it wouldn't be much cleaner than JS indeed (because the use of seperate backgound image for each element).

Comment: You can check this on http://2013.greenfestival.pt/index.php/greenfest-13/tematicas/

Try in Chrome and in IE. Just hover the road Av. Portugal.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done really easier with css `hover` selector.. `CSS` already has that implemented..

You're kinda re-inventing the wheel.

Just add anything you want to happen when you `hover` to the `hover` selector of that css element:

```
.expositores1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 306px;
    height: 122px;
    margin-left: 11px;
    margin-top: 146px;
    background-color: #F00;
}
.expositores1:hover {
    background-color: #00F;
}
```

And better your browser will switch back to the normal selector after you move your mouse out..
No need to have javascript do it for you.

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6zrX/) I created for you.

Comment: But what about changing the background of the other three divs (all based on hovering over the first)?

Comment: Actually I can't do .expositores:hover because I want several background-image changed, and with .expositores:hover it will change only "this" div.

Comment: Hugo - you can change all of the backgrounds on hover of the first: http://jsbin.com/isequv/1/edit (assuming the divs in question are siblings as shown in the question).

Comment: I've tried it now and it does not work in IE but works in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: You can check this on http://2013.greenfestival.pt/index.php/greenfest-13/tematicas/

Try in Chrome and in IE. Just hover the road Av. Portugal.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution: define background for div when it is not hover. Now it works in IE..

Thank you, I learned a lot of things with you answers.

Regards,
Hugo

Comment: @HugoSousa Yeah you should do it. Because the browser just applies the css to the element. If you don't define any background, the background will not change